# ctable footnotes - automatic labeling?

Tags: footnotes, ctable

Is there a way to have [`ctable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable) automatically label the footnotes: a, b, c, etc... (or some other formatting)?

```
\ctable[
] {rl} {
    \tnote{first footnote}
    \tnote{second footnote}
}{
    \FL Configuration & Error
    \ML Full\tmark & 0.0
    \ML Partial\tmark & 0.0
    \LL
}
```

The above code marks them all as footnote a.  Obviously I could specify each individually (`\tnote[a]{}`, `\tnote[b]{}`), but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automation is currently not part of [`ctable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable), since numbering is done using an optional argument to both `\tnote[<num>]` and `\tmark[<num>]`.

Based on your (very) minimal example, the following should suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcounter{ctabfnote}\newcounter{ctabfmark}
\renewcommand{\thectabfnote}{\alph{ctabfnote}}
\renewcommand{\thectabfmark}{\alph{ctabfmark}}
\pretocmd{\ctable}% <cmd>
  {\setcounter{ctabfnote}{0}%
   \setcounter{ctabfmark}{0}}% <prepend>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tnote}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{ctabfnote}%
   \ifx\@ctblnotespar\@ctbltrue%
     \@ctbltextsuperscript{\normalfont\textit{\thectabfnote}}\,#1
   \else%
     \hbox{\@ctbltextsuperscript{\normalfont\textit{\thectabfnote}}}&#1\NN
   \fi
}
\renewcommand{\tmark}{%
  \stepcounter{ctabfmark}%
   \hbox{\textsuperscript{\normalfont\textit{\thectabfmark}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ctable[
] {rl} {
    \tnote{first footnote}
    \tnote{second footnote}
}{
    \FL Configuration & Error
    \ML Full\tmark & 0.0
    \ML Partial\tmark & 0.0
    \LL
}

\end{document}
```

Two new counters are introduced, one for each of `\tnote` and `\tmark`. I've also modified the input to `\tnote` and `\tmark` to drop the optional argument, since they're not needed anymore. Counter are reset at the start of `\ctable` (via a patch thanks to [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)).

Comment: This is really awesome! For my (and others') future reference, you can change the counter (to numbers, symbols, etc...) by changing: `\alph{ctabfnote}` to `\roman`, `\fnsymbol`, etc...